# 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, list, api, dart, dictionary

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'; import 'package:http/http.dart' as http; import 'dart:convert' as convert; import 'package:flutter_application_1/Model/Currency.dart';

void main() { runApp(const MyApp()); }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { const MyApp({super.key});

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return MaterialApp( localizationsDelegates: const [ GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate, GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, ], supportedLocales: const [ Locale('fa'), // Persian ], theme: ThemeData( fontFamily: "IranSans", textTheme: const TextTheme( displayLarge: TextStyle( fontFamily: "IranSans", fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700), bodyLarge: TextStyle( fontFamily: "IranSans", fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300), displayMedium: TextStyle( fontFamily: "IranSans", fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300))), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: HomePage(), ); } }

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget { HomePage({ super.key, });

@override State createState() => _HomePageState(); }

class _HomePageState extends State { List currency = [];

getResponse() { var url = "http://api.navasan.tech/latest/?api_key=freeTFyHoFiXvgG6UNOlQHfehDasa7eK"; http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then((value) { print(value.statusCode); if (value.statusCode == 200) { List jsonList = convert.jsonDecode(value.body); if (jsonList.length > 0) { for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.length; i++) { setState(() { currency.add(Currency( id: jsonList[i], value: jsonList[i]["value"], change: jsonList[i]["change"], timestamp: jsonList[i]['timestamp'], date: jsonList[i]["date"])); }); } } } }); }

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { getResponse(); return Scaffold( backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 243, 243), appBar: AppBar( elevation: 0, backgroundColor: Colors.white, actions: [ const SizedBox( width: 12, ), Image.asset("assets/images/currency.png"), Align( alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text("قیمت به روز ارز", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge), ), Expanded( child: Align( alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Image.asset("assets/images/menu.png")), ), const SizedBox( width: 12, ), ], ), body: SingleChildScrollView( child: Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0), child: Column( children: [ Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [ Image.asset("assets/images/questionMark.png"), const SizedBox( width: 8, ), Text("نرخ ارز آزاد چیست؟", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge), ], ), const SizedBox( height: 12, ), Text( "مقصود از نرخ ارز آزاد، نرخ خرید و فروش ارز در بازار غیررسمی و غیردولتی است. از آنجایی که اغلب مبادلات عموم مردم در این بازار به انجام می رسد و دسترسی به آن برای همگان امکان پذیر است لذا این نرخ از بیشترین وجاهت و مقبولیت عمومی برخوردار است و محاسبات و مبادلات عمدتا بر مبنای آن صورت می پذیرد. ", textAlign: TextAlign.justify, textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, ), Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 24, 0, 0), child: Container( width: double.infinity, height: 35, decoration: const BoxDecoration( color: Color.fromARGB(255, 130, 130, 130), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))), child: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, children: [ Text( 'نام آزاد ارز', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium, ), Text( 'قیمت', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium, ), Text( 'تغییر', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium, ) ], ), ), ), SizedBox( height: 350, width: double.infinity, child: ListView.separated( itemCount: currency.length, scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(), itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) { return Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0), child: MyItem(position, currency), ); }, separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { if (index % 9 == 0) { return const Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0), child: Ad(), ); } else { return const SizedBox.shrink(); } }, ), ), Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 0), child: Container( width: double.infinity, height: 50, decoration: const BoxDecoration( color: Color.fromARGB(255, 232, 232, 232), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100)), ), child: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [ SizedBox( height: 50, child: TextButton.icon( style: const ButtonStyle( shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll< RoundedRectangleBorder>( RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(100)), side: BorderSide( width: 1, color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, ))), backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll( Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 193, 255))), onPressed: () => _showSnackBar( context, "بروز رسانی با موفقیت انجام شد."), icon: const Icon( CupertinoIcons.refresh_bold, color: Colors.black, ), label: Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0), child: Text( 'بروز رسانی', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge, ), )), ), Text( 'آخرین بروز رسانی ${_getTime()}', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, ), const SizedBox( width: 8, ) ], ), ), ) ], ), ), )); }

String _getTime() { return "20:45"; } }

void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String msg) {
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar( content: Text( msg, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium, ), duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating, backgroundColor: Colors.green, showCloseIcon: true, dismissDirection: DismissDirection.up, closeIconColor: Colors.white, padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 15, 5), shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))), )); }

class MyItem extends StatelessWidget { int position;
List currency; MyItem( this.position, this.currency, );

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Container( height: 50, decoration: const BoxDecoration( boxShadow: [ BoxShadow( blurRadius: 1, color: Colors.grey, ) ], color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))), child: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [ Text( currency[position].id!, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, ), Text( currency[position].value!, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, ), Text( currency[position].change.toString(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge, ) ], ), ); } }

class Ad extends StatelessWidget { const Ad({ super.key, });

@override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Container( height: 50, decoration: const BoxDecoration( boxShadow: [ BoxShadow( blurRadius: 1, color: Colors.grey, ) ], color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))), child: Center( child: Text( 'Advertisement', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium, ))); } }







model class: 
 Currency { String? id; String? value; int? change; int? timestamp; String? date; Currency({ required this.id, required this.value, required this.change, required this.timestamp, required this.date, }); }






API : 
"harat_naghdi_buy": { "value": "49970", "change": -720, "timestamp": 1678374494, "date": "1401-12-18 18:38:14" }, "harat_naghdi_sell": { "value": "49950", "change": -790, "timestamp": 1678374150, "date": "1401-12-18 18:32:30" },
```

I'm building a Flutter app which fetches data from an Api,when I run the app here is the error I get : Flutter 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I believe the API is sort of map<string, dynamic> but I don't know how to bring it into the code. As I made a model for the api variables.

Comment: can you format the part and include only necessary part

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Map as response, instead of list. You can try like

```dart
if (value.statusCode == 200) {
  Map jsonList = convert.jsonDecode(value.body);
  if (jsonList.length > 0) {
    jsonList.forEach((key, value) {
      currency.add(Currency(
          id: jsonList[key],
          value: jsonList[key]["value"],
          change: jsonList[key]["change"],
          timestamp: jsonList[key]['timestamp'],
          date: jsonList[key]["date"]));
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```